# RabbitMQ connection issues

Tags: c#, rabbitmq

I'm trying to track down an issue with RabbitMQ dropping connections and failing to reconnect so I've simplified it to this code block to try to track it down but still can't figure it out. Here's a code sample

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    try
    {
        currentConnection = factory.CreateConnection();
        Console.WriteLine("connected " + i);
        currentConnection.Close();
        Console.WriteLine("closed " + i);
        currentConnection.Dispose();

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("fail " + ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Seems very straightforward but this is what I'm seeing and **I've tried using two different servers at two different locations and with and without TLS with and without multiple endpoints/nodes** and the results are always the same where sometimes it'll connect and sometimes it won't:

```
connected 0
closed 0
fail None of the specified endpoints were reachable
fail None of the specified endpoints were reachable
connected 3
closed 3
fail None of the specified endpoints were reachable
```

The server logs are filled with "{handshake_timeout,frame_header}" errors but I'm not sure what that means or what I could do differently.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you do that test, but in real application you don't have to open and close many connections (in fact one) and use channels (IModel).

https://www.rabbitmq.com/channels.html.

Why it's failed ? I don't know, maybe TCP port saturation waiting freeing resources.

If application lose the connection (network issue) you have to recreate one and maybe some retries.

Comment: I want to have and use only one connection but when it fails, it randomly won't reconnect and I can reproduce that easily with this code. What I don't know is why it's happening from multiple servers even with a fresh install. I would expect it either wouldn't connect at all, or would connect 100% of the time.

Comment: Maybe you can add a delay between retry to avoid saturation.

Comment: Opening, closing, and reopening a connection just once can cause "saturation"? That doesn't sound very robust.

Comment: I don't know, but I do delay on retry when it lost connection, to consume less CPU on client in fact.